# What is Lindel's song from Ancient Magus Bride based on?

Tags: music, the-ancient-magus-bride

The song currently has no official title. But the first two words are "Iruna Etelero", thought it is often called "Flower Song". Some have theorized it's Finnish.

Is it just random syllables?

(Song link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLky9RjDXoY)

Comment: Actually, the official title is イルナエテルロ (*Iruna Eteruro*), but I believe what you're asking about is the origin/background/language of the song? Also, [the unofficial lyric](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13183947008).

Comment: I didn't know there was an official title. I just saw a dozen different titles on youtube.

Comment: I'm basically looking for any background I can find. So all of those things, and possibly a lyric translation (not all of it, some of it)

Comment: As of now, I don't think there's an official explanation since [this tweet (Japanese) by the composer himself](https://twitter.com/sirato10/status/946248517613264897) said "to wait until the production team permit him to release the info" ... which probably will be [in March 2018](https://www.lisani.jp/0000066987/) when the 2nd OST that includes this song is released (Just a future reminder to other answerers and myself). Also, [the copyable, unofficial lyric](https://ameblo.jp/moontears917/entry-12342118336.html)

Answer (score -3):

I just looked up info for the soundtrack for Season 2 and [CDJapan has it on preorder to be released on March 28th](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/VTCL-60469). I also looked around at other sites and all of them say the 28th, so I am going to say unless we hear otherwise, this *should* be the official release date.

Also, pertaining to the lyrics, I ran them through Google Translate and it tagged them as Finnish, but the only words that were translated to English were Satoa (Harvest) and Toimessez (Actress)

However, I am running each word (Japanese) through to see if I get anything. Here is what it gave me

> Iruna (Bengali) eteruro (Japanese)
>     Please obtain
>
> Iruna eteruro
>   Please obtain
>
> Nadia, ēzeruvu~ōte (Swahili)
>   Nadia, wisely ~ ok
>
> Reizeruko, (Swahili) mikemesuta (Igbo)
>   Resurrection, lightning
>
> Iruna eteruro
>   Please obtain
>
> Iruna eteruro
>   Please obtain
>
> Sātoa, (Swahili) aimeltewa (Swahili)
>   Offer, beautifully
>
> Reizeruko, mikemesuta
>   Resurrection, lightning
>
> Āmeru, mikerumo (Igbo)
>   Eat, slide
>
> Toimesesu, (Latvian) mikerumo (Igbo)
>   For the better, slide
>
> Maseri, (Swahili) īmekuu~ōze (Latvian)
>   Masters, you know
>
> Tōwa~ana, (Igbo) Mizaimesuta (Latvian)
>   Drums, peeling
>
> Kesera, (Swahili) Kesera (Swahili)
>   The trial, the trial
>
> Kesera, (Swahili) Setoru (Japanese)
>   The trial, settle
>
> Āmeruvu~a, (Igbo) Eterurovu~o (Japanese)
>   Activate ~ a, Get it now ~
>
> Mītetevu~a, (Swahili) Maria, (Latin) Ezeruvu~ōte, (Swahili)
>   Defense, Maria, Wisdom ~ Oto
>
> Reizeruko, mikemesuta
>   Resurrection, lightning

So yeah, it makes some sort of sense, but who knows if that is what it actually is saying.